# Keep a timer running when i close the application in unity3d

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm currently developing a unity game wish have a counter that reset every 5 hrs , i am facing a problem in keeping this timer active even when i close the application for example : if it was the first time i open the app the timer is `0` and keep getting up till it reach `5 hrs`. if i close the app before the `5 hrs finish` and i come back later i should see the amount of time passed since the last close of the app and `compare it again to see if it reached 5 hrs or no`

I am currently developing this app for unity android

What I did so far :

```
  public static int Sec=PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Sec",0);
  public static int Current_Min=PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CurrentMin",0);
  public static int Max_min = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MaxMin",5*60);

  void Start()
  {
       InvokeRepeating("GetDate",0,1f);
  }

  void GetDate()
  {
        Sec++;
        if (Sec == 60){
            Sec = 0;
            Current_Min++;
       }
       if(Current_Min==Max_min)
       {
          // do something ....
       }
  }
  void OnApplicationQuit()
  {
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Sec",Sec);
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("CurrentMin",Current_Min);
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MaxMin",Max_min);
     PlayerPrefs.Save();
  }
```

Comment: Can't you get a `DateTime.Now` on closing and a timer value, and then, on restart, just count passed time by comparing saved values and current values?

Comment: i did not understand can you please provide an example ?

Comment: I am not very skilled in Unity, and I do not have access to it at the time, but you certainly have events, something called OnClosing or similiar - the event that is raised when your app is about to close. You have as well an event which is raised when app starts - this is probably called OnStart. When OnClosing is raised, you need to save time of closing and value of timer. When app is starting next time, simply add difference between closing time and starting time to timer.

Comment: can you check my edit please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking for is a way to persist a piece of information between play sessions of your user.
Data persistance is a broader concept that is used throughout game development.
Ie, save games, high scores, user preference settings, etc.

You can find a tutorial on persiting data between scenes as well as between app execututions here: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/persistence-data-saving-loading

What you specifically need is to save current_min and sec values on game close and load them back up the next time the user starts your game.

You can also consider not counting up seconds, but rather storing a date time value of the last "event" and then simply checking if current date time is equal or higher than the previous time + 5 hours.

Note that neither of these approaches is inherently "safe" from hinderence by the user. Ie, deleting your game's user data or changing the system clock, etc.

So do not use this approach for sensitive things such as trial limitations or actons in multiplayer games. For that, you need outside verification / authorization that doesn't rely on information stored on the user's device

EDIT

You have edited your original question and inserted the part that saves data to player preferences on close.
You are still missing the part which would load ti back up on start, before calling the invoke timer.

I strongly suggest you go through the entire tutorial I originally linked, as it will show you the correct way to handle these sort of things.

You did not explain what you are using the "timer" for, but I suspect it should be a part of a larger game save / load process that you need to implement for your users. Simply hacking in this one functionality is trivial, but you should setup your game such that you gracefully handle resuming gameplay between app executuions, and for that you need to research more.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the changes you made to the code in your question

Comment: if i want to use a time and not a variable called Sec . how can i check if some amount of time is passed or not for example : if the max time to pass is 5 hrs and i should take `4 pictures durring this 5 hrs` that mean take a picture every `5hr/4` , how can i do this if i am using a `time variable` and not an `int`

Comment: thank you for your answer ^-^ , please consider reading my previous comment